# After TYPO3 Update from 6.2 to 7.6 still errors in TCA?

Tags: typo3, upgrade

I've made an update from `TYPO3 CMS 6.2` to `TYPO3 CMS 7.6.16`. After a few problems with other extensions (`tx_news`and `third party ext.`) and the [changes](https://www.clickstorm.de/blog/typo3-tca-7-6/) in the `TCA`. Everything works fine after import live-dump ...

1. Upgrade wizard / Database compare
2. Update reference Index
3. Flush Cache and empty `typo3temp`
4. Deactivate and reactivate the Extensions with problems

Everything? Unfortunately, no. The extension doesn't work. I don't written the extension by myself. If I try to add a new data record in **backend** with this ext., I'll get this error:

```
An item in field form of table tx_blah_domain_model_job is not an array as expected
```

But the database comprare is finished. All tables are correct?!

[image: typo3 database compare]

Where's the problem? I know it's hard to analyze this without source code. There's a database field wrong, but why? It's the same database like before?

Where's the fault .. `ext_tables.php` or still sth. in `TCA` is wrong? I really need a tip .. its frustrating ..

**EDIT:** sys_log entry

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1439288036: An item in field form of table tx_blah_domain_model_job is not an array as expected | UnexpectedValueException thrown in file /typo3_src/typo3_src-7.6.16/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/FormDataProvider/AbstractItemProvider.php in line 1264.
```

**EDIT 2:** I think, there must be sth. in `typo3conf/ext/blah/Configuration/TCA/tx_blah_domain_model_job.php`
see [TCA source code](https://jsfiddle.net/edw4v1b8/)

and that's in line 1264

```
/**
 * Sanitize incoming item array
 *
 * Used by TcaSelectItems and TcaSelectTreeItems data providers
 *
 * @param mixed $itemArray
 * @param string $tableName
 * @param string $fieldName
 * @throws \UnexpectedValueException
 * @return array
 */
public function sanitizeItemArray($itemArray, $tableName, $fieldName)
{
    if (!is_array($itemArray)) {
        $itemArray = [];
    }
    foreach ($itemArray as $item) {
        if (!is_array($item)) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException(
                'An item in field ' . $fieldName . ' of table ' . $tableName . ' is not an array as expected',
                1439288036
            );
        }
    }

    return $itemArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the error log for an more adavanced error including an error trace? This could help to find out the source of the misconfiguration (in your TCA I guess).

Comment: Hi Paul. I will update my post in the evening, because I'm on the road now .... thanks for your comment.

Comment: I've edit my post and add the sys_log error and the File from core `typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/FormDataProvider/AbstractItemProvider.php` - ok the problem is in the `TCA`.I thought I've fixed all TCA-Bugs ... mmh?

Comment: I've posted the source code from my TCA-file: https://jsfiddle.net/edw4v1b8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aTry to use this in the TCA tx_imappointments_domain_model_job.php

```
        'form' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:im_appointments/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_imappointments_domain_model_job.form',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'items' => array(array('', 0)),
                'foreign_table' => 'pages',
                'foreign_table_where' => ' AND pages.pid = 293',
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            ),
        ),
```

'items' in 'form' has to be a array how your error message said:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#items

Comment: Hi Heinz. Thanks for your advice. I think, I've got it. It was `... 'items' => array(array('', 0),), ...` instead of  `items' => array(''), ..` before. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are right. I fixed my answer if you like to accept it as right answer.